# How to open Action Text Trix attachments or links in new window (target _blank)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix, actiontext, stimulusjs

How to make links that I add in Trix (ActionText) editor open the link in a new window with target="_blank"?

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :rich_text_content
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a Stimulus controller `richtext_controller.js` :

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    this.element.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(link) {
      if (link.host !== window.location.host) {
        link.target = "_blank"
      }
    })
  }
}
```

add your content like this :

```
<div data-controller="richtext">
  <%= post.rich_text_content %>
</div>
```